# ElasticSearch Multiple Sub Aggregation Queries Use 1.5G Memory With Only 25 MB Documents

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Can anyone help me take a look to this query builder and help me optimize it? Can someone also tell me why the collection model "breath_first" doesn't make difference to "depth_first"? This Query is keep hitting my circuit breaker request limit and cause OOM. The index metadata mapping fields are just flat listed, no nested fields.

```
    final FilterBuilder filterBuilder = termFilter("month", getMostRecentMonthToQuery(indexId));

    final String revenueScript = getRevenueScript(revenueModifier);

    final String sortString = convertTermSortToAggregationSort(sortColumn);
    final boolean isAscending = sortOrder.equalsIgnoreCase("asc");
    final SubAggCollectionMode aggCollectionMode = SubAggCollectionMode.parse("breadth_first");

    final SearchRequestBuilder builder = elasticSearchClient.prepareSearch(indexId)
            .setTypes(TYPE_NAME)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), filterBuilder))
            .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("carCount")
                .field(CAR_RAW)
                .size(pageSize)
                .order(Terms.Order.aggregation(sortString, isAscending))
                .collectMode(aggCollectionMode)
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("partProviderCount")
                    .field(PART_PROVIDER_RAW)
                    .size(0)
                )
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.cardinality("partCount")
                    .field(PART_NUMBER_RAW)
                    .precisionThreshold(40000)
                )
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg(IGPART_AGG_NAME)
                    .field(IGPART_TERM_NAME)
                )
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg(CGPART_AGG_NAME)
                    .field(CGPART_TERM_NAME)
                )
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg(OGPART_AGG_NAME)
                    .field(OGPART_TERM_NAME)
                )
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg(CPPART_AGG_NAME)
                    .field(CPPART_TERM_NAME)
                )
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum(IGPART_PRICE_AGG_NAME)
                    .field(IGPART_TERM_NAME)
                    .script(revenueScript)
                )
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum(CGPART_PRICE_AGG_NAME)
                    .field(CGPART_TERM_NAME)
                    .script(revenueScript)
                )
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum(OGPART_PRICE_AGG_NAME)
                    .field(OGPART_TERM_NAME)
                    .script(revenueScript)
                )
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum(CPPART_PRICE_AGG_NAME)
                    .field(CPPART_TERM_NAME)
                    .script(revenueScript)
                )
            );
    return builder;
```